# Exchange two elements of a vector in one call

Tags: r

I have a vector `c(9,6,3,4,2,1,5,7,8)`, and I want to switch the elements at index 2 and at index 5 in the vector. However, I don't want to have to create a temporary variable and would like to make the switch in one call. How would I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `replace()`.

```
x <- c(9, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8)
replace(x, c(2, 5), x[c(5, 2)])
# [1] 9 2 3 4 6 1 5 7 8
```

And if you don't even want to assign `x`, you can use

```
replace(
    c(9, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8), 
    c(2, 5), 
    c(9, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8)[c(5, 2)]
)
# [1] 9 2 3 4 6 1 5 7 8
```

but that's a bit silly.  You will probably want `x` assigned to begin with.

Comment: note that `replace` is just a wrapper for `x[c(2, 5)] = x[c(5, 2)]`.

Answer (score 25):

How about just `x[c(i,j)] <- x[c(j,i)]`? Similar to `replace(...)`, but perhaps a bit simpler.

```
swtch <- function(x,i,j) {x[c(i,j)] <- x[c(j,i)]; x} 
swtch(c(9,6,3,4,2,1,5,7,8) , 2,5)
# [1] 9 2 3 4 6 1 5 7 8
```

Answer (score 6):

If you actually want to do it without creating a temporary copy of the vector, you would need to write a short C function.

```
library(inline)
swap <- cfunction(c(i = "integer", j = "integer", vec="integer"),"
                  int *v = INTEGER(vec);
                  int ii = INTEGER(i)[0]-1, jj = INTEGER(j)[0]-1;
                  int tmp = v[ii];
                  v[ii] = v[jj];
                  v[jj] = tmp;
                  return R_NilValue;
                  ")

vec <- as.integer(c(9,6,3,4,2,1,5,7,8))
swap(2L, 5L, vec)

vec
# [1] 9 2 3 4 6 1 5 7 8
```