# R: Swap two variables without using a third

Tags: r

I have two variables (i.e.):

```
   a <- 1
   b <- 2
```

and I would like to swap their values. Is there any built-in R function, that is able to perform that operation? Or is there an other elegant way, without using a third (temp) variable?

**Note:** If possible applicable on strings, or other datatypes.

Comment: Once you overwrite one variable, its information is -- puff -- gone. So, no, not without using "hacks" like storing them in different environments.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you don't want a temp variable. Because otherwise you can only do 'tricks' like the existing answers which only work for numbers and are also not 'better' with respect to readability and so on. You can also look at this: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Generic_swap#R

Comment: How about using one of your variables a, b itself as a temp storage - would that be allowed? If so, you could do things like `a <- list(a, b); b <- a[[1]]; a <- a[[2]]` and that should also work for strings etc

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470937/how-would-i-exchange-two-elements-of-a-vector-in-one-r-call

Comment: Sorry for the necro-post, but I have added another possible answer.  Shame there isn't  an exchange  `a<->b` operator really, but hopefully the `swap()` function I have provided may help.

Comment: I kinda miss how you can do `a, b = b, a` in Python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For integers, you can use

```
a = a + b
b = a - b
a = a - b
```

and for strings, this would work

```
a <- "one"
b <- "two"
a <- paste(a,b, sep = "")
b <- substr(a,0,nchar(a) - nchar(b))
a <- substr(a,nchar(b) + 1, nchar(a))

> a
# two
> b 
# one
```

Answer (score 15):

There is general solution or 'trick' for that:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2

a <- a + b
b <- a - b
a <- a - b
```

Here's a useful link that explains a lot: [xor-trick](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/25/xor-trick/)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43804323/1895415) abbreviates the 'trick' to a one-liner:  `a  <- b - a + (b <- a)` which makes it clear why it works. [The open parenthesis function returns the result of evaluating its argument](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Paren.html) `b <- a` (but with visibility set, useful for e.g. `(invisible(5))`), while the [assignment operator returns the value assigned](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html) which is `a`. So we are effectively looking at  `a <- b - a + a` and we assigned `b <- a`!

Answer (score 6):

The good thing about having *way* too many functions in the base package: there's always a way to do something, even if it's a bad idea.

```
list2env(list(a = b, b = a), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

This works no matter what the classes of `a` and `b` are.  But I repeat: **this is a bad idea.**

Comment: Really neat! Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is a bad idea? I am assuming readability, but is performance also an issue?

Comment: I don't actually know what happens under the hood of `list2env`.  The end result, if `envir` is given, is using a named list to assign objects in that environment using the list's name/value pairs. It's a bad idea because (1) yes, this is hard to understand when reading, and (2) playing with environments can easily have unintended consequences. Case in point, my code above commits the grave crime of explicitly assigning to `.GlobalEnv`. If a script has this, no other script can source it without messing up the environment.

Answer (score 3):

Start

```
A = 9
B = 5
A = A + B
```

Then

```
A is 14
B is 5
B = A - B
```

Then

```
A is 14
B is 9
A = A - B
```

Result:

A(5) is now B

B(9) is now A

Not really simpler then just using a third variable but i works!

Comment: The solution in the post above is easier. In R, you could write `a  <- (b-a) + (b <- a) `

Answer (score 2):

While the previous answers are all fine and pretty, they all take up too much space for my liking!

So I've come up with a tidier solution in C:

```
a = (b - a) + (b = a);
```

It doesn't work with strings, but both integers and floating points work just fine.

It works like so:

```
int a = 5, b = 7;
a = (b - a) + (b = a);
/* turns into */
a = (7 - 5) + (b = 5);
/* b is now 5 */
a = 2 + 5;
/* a is now 7 */
```

The key here is the order at which expressions are parsed (left to right). Because of that, the first occurrence of *b* in the expression is replaced by *b*'s original value, and only after that is *b* assigned to *a*.

I realize that this is an old and already answered question, but perhaps this will be useful to someone out there

Answer (score 2):

Based on Nathan's post, to keep the variable-swap within the running environment:

```
x <- 10
y <- 20
list2env(list(x=y, y=x), envir=as.environment(environment()))
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no built in function to do this, and no general way you can swap two variables without having a third.

However, if you are after a function that will at least reduce code repetition the following may help:

```
swap <- function(x,y) {
  eval( parse( text = paste(
    "swap_unique_var_a<-", substitute(x), ";",
    substitute(x), "<-", substitute(y), ";",
    substitute(y), "<-swap_unique_var_a") ), env=parent.frame() )
}
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
a<-1; b<-2;
swap(a,b)
print(a); print(b)
```

The two arguments of the function `swap()` refer to two variables in the local frame, which it then swaps creating a temporary in order to do so.

Current limitations / issues with the `swap()` function:

- Temporary is created in the `parent.frame()` which is where you are calling the `swap()` from.
- Arguments `x` and `y` are assumed to be in the `parent.frame()` environment, so variables in the global environment are re-created in the `parent.frame()` environment.

It may be possible to make the function more robust, but I am a little concerned about the impact on performance, especially in an interpreted language such as R without the equivalent of in-lining.

If there is interest / time I will test performance and see if a more robust version is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporary store values in a `list` and also make an assignment inside it. But I don't recommend this way, just to show another possibility.

```
a <- 1
b <- 2

b <- list(a, a <- b)[[1]]

a
#[1] 2
b
#[1] 1
```

Using a temporary variable might be easier to read and might be more performant.

```
a <- 1
b <- 2

. <- a
a <- b
b <- .
rm(.)

a
#[1] 2
b
#[1] 1
```