# With dplyr, how to update two twisted columns in parallel, rather than an iterative manner?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dummy dataframe `df` like below

```
> set.seed(1)
> df <- data.frame(x = runif(5), y = rnorm(5), val = sample(letters, 5))

> df
          x          y val
1 0.2655087  1.2724293   j
2 0.3721239  0.4146414   v
3 0.5728534 -1.5399500   n
4 0.9082078 -0.9285670   z
5 0.2016819 -0.2947204   g
```

and I would like to mutate columns `x` and `y`, such that the new `x=pmin(x,y)` and `y=pmax(x,y)`.

## Expected

I hope above two steps run at the same time, instead of sequential executions, and `transform` from base R can give the desired output like

```
> transform(df, x = pmin(x, y),y = pmax(x, y))
           x         y val
1  0.2655087 1.2724293   j
2  0.3721239 0.4146414   v
3 -1.5399500 0.5728534   n
4 -0.9285670 0.9082078   z
5 -0.2947204 0.2016819   g
```

## Question

However, I am wondering how this can be done with `dplyr` (I don't have much knowledge about it before and thus learning it now), since I am aware that the following code is indeed acting in a sequential manner, like, mutating `x_new=pmin(x,y)` first, and then the newly generated `x` enters the iteration to update `y_new = pmax(x_new,y)`.

**So, is it possible to avoid introducing intermediate variable to make it if we use `dplyr`?**

```
> df %>%
+   mutate(x = pmin(x, y), y = pmax(x, y))
           x          y val
1  0.2655087  1.2724293   j
2  0.3721239  0.4146414   v
3 -1.5399500 -1.5399500   n
4 -0.9285670 -0.9285670   z
5 -0.2947204 -0.2947204   g
```

Is there any `dplyr` implementation that works in the same way as `transform` did? Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @Ritchie Sacramento pointed already in the comment and @dufei has shown in an answer, you have to change the scope. An additional way is using `.$x` to get the original values of `x` what is possible when piping the data with `%>%`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(x = pmin(x, y), y = pmax(.$x, y))
#           x         y val
#1  0.2655087 1.2724293   j
#2  0.3721239 0.4146414   v
#3 -1.5399500 0.5728534   n
#4 -0.9285670 0.9082078   z
#5 -0.2947204 0.2016819   g
```

A way *with* a named temporary variable, which will be removed afterwards with `select`.

```
df %>% mutate(tmp = pmin(x, y), y = pmax(x, y), x = tmp) %>% select(-tmp)
#           x         y val
#1  0.2655087 1.2724293   j
#2  0.3721239 0.4146414   v
#3 -1.5399500 0.5728534   n
#4 -0.9285670 0.9082078   z
#5 -0.2947204 0.2016819   g
```

Or using `local` as described at [temporary variables in mutate()](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5937).

```
df %>%
  mutate(local({
    X <- x
    data.frame(x = pmin(X, y), y = pmax(X, y))
  }))
#           x         y val
#1  0.2655087 1.2724293   j
#2  0.3721239 0.4146414   v
#3 -1.5399500 0.5728534   n
#4 -0.9285670 0.9082078   z
#5 -0.2947204 0.2016819   g
```

What is very close to the solution from @Ritchie Sacramento in the comment.

```
df %>% mutate(data.frame(x = pmin(x, y), y = pmax(x, y)))
#           x         y val
#1  0.2655087 1.2724293   j
#2  0.3721239 0.4146414   v
#3 -1.5399500 0.5728534   n
#4 -0.9285670 0.9082078   z
#5 -0.2947204 0.2016819   g
```

In fact the calculations also in `transform` are not done *in parallel* and also in this case there will not be used less memory by avoiding an intermediate named value.
Also note that the manual of `transform` includes a *Warning*: *This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting arithmetic functions, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument ‘transform’ can have unanticipated consequences.*
Alternatives avoiding `transform` and `mutate` but giving the desired result might be:

```
. <- pmin(df$x, df$y)  #Classic way
df$y <- pmax(df$x, df$y)
df$x <- .
rm(.)

df[c("x", "y")] <- list(pmin(df$x, df$y), pmax(df$x, df$y))

df[c("x", "y")] <- with(df, list(pmin(x, y), pmax(x, y)))

df[c("x", "y")] <- cbind(pmin(df$x, df$y), pmax(df$x, df$y)) #Not recommended: Will casts results to the same type, connect two vectors which are then disconnected again

df$x <- pmin(df$x, df$y, df$y <- pmax(df$x, df$y)) #Not recommended

i <- df$x > df$y
df[i, c("x", "y")] <- df[i, c("y", "x")]
```

---

Memory usage - Starting each with a new `--vanilla` session.

```
#Base Classic
n <- 1e6
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(n), y = rnorm(n), val = sample(letters, n, TRUE))
gctorture(on = TRUE)
m0 <- gc(reset=TRUE)
. <- pmin(df$x, df$y)
df$y <- pmax(df$x, df$y)
df$x <- .
rm(.)
gc() - m0
#       used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells 1836  0.1          0  0.0     1913  0.1
#Vcells 4330  0.0    3866986 29.6  2005429 15.3
```

```
#Transform
n <- 1e6
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(n), y = rnorm(n), val = sample(letters, n, TRUE))
gctorture(on = TRUE)
m0 <- gc(reset=TRUE)
df <- transform(df, x = pmin(x, y),y = pmax(x, y))
gc() - m0
#        used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells  4648  0.3          0  0.0     4842  0.3
#Vcells 11670  0.0    3866986 29.6  2030050 15.4
```

```
#.$x
library(dplyr)
n <- 1e6
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(n), y = rnorm(n), val = sample(letters, n, TRUE))
gctorture(on = TRUE)
m0 <- gc(reset=TRUE)
df <- df %>% mutate(x = pmin(x, y), y = pmax(.$x, y))
gc() - m0
#        used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells 20373  1.0          0  0.0    20609  1.1
#Vcells 41322  0.3    3866986 29.6  2043345 15.6
```

```
#Local
library(dplyr)
n <- 1e6
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(n), y = rnorm(n), val = sample(letters, n, TRUE))
gctorture(on = TRUE)
m0 <- gc(reset=TRUE)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(local({
    X <- x
    data.frame(x = pmin(X, y), y = pmax(X, y))
  }))
gc() - m0
#        used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells 20365  1.0          0  0.0    20666  1.1
#Vcells 41293  0.3    3866986 29.6  2043878 15.6
```

```
#Data.frame
library(dplyr)
n <- 1e6
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(n), y = rnorm(n), val = sample(letters, n, TRUE))
gctorture(on = TRUE)
m0 <- gc(reset=TRUE)
df <- df %>% mutate(data.frame(x = pmin(x, y), y = pmax(x, y)))
gc() - m0
#        used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells 20360  1.0          0  0.0    20608  1.1
#Vcells 41293  0.3    3866986 29.6  2043837 15.6
```

```
#.[1:3]
library(dplyr)
n <- 1e6
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(n), y = rnorm(n), val = sample(letters, n, TRUE))
gctorture(on = TRUE)
m0 <- gc(reset=TRUE)
df <- df %>% mutate(tmp = pmin(x, y), y = pmax(x, y), x = tmp) %>% .[1:3]
gc() - m0
#        used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells 20375  1.1          0  0.0    20630  1.1
#Vcells 41322  0.3    3866986 29.6  2043354 15.6
```

```
#-select
library(dplyr)
n <- 1e6
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(n), y = rnorm(n), val = sample(letters, n, TRUE))
gctorture(on = TRUE)
m0 <- gc(reset=TRUE)
df <- df %>% mutate(tmp = pmin(x, y), y = pmax(x, y), x = tmp) %>% select(-tmp)
gc() - m0
#        used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#Ncells 33733  1.8          0  0.0    34142  1.8
#Vcells 66987  0.5    3866986 29.6  2068178 15.8
```

Result

```
base classic: 15.4 Mb
transform   : 15.7 Mb
.$x         : 16.7 Mb
local       : 16.7 Mb
data.frame  : 16.7 Mb
.[1:3]      : 16.7 Mb
-select     : 17.6 Mb
```

Maybe have also a look at [R: Swap two variables without using a third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585753).

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there's a direct equivalent of `transform` in dplyr - there is quite some effort put in to making `mutate` behave in this way, and if you want the behaviour of `transform`, then there is no reason to change it. `transform` works well in the pipe and mostly does what `mutate` does, except the (often desirable) ability to sequentially change variables as you have demonstrated.

If you want to do this in dplyr, you need a temporary variable that you can rename inside `select`, so we can do:

```r
mutate(df, X = pmin(x, y), y = pmax(x, y)) %>% select(x = X, y, val)
#>            x         y val
#> 1  0.2655087 1.2724293   j
#> 2  0.3721239 0.4146414   v
#> 3 -1.5399500 0.5728534   n
#> 4 -0.9285670 0.9082078   z
#> 5 -0.2947204 0.2016819   g
```

But this is not as good as:

```r
df |> transform(x = pmin(x, y),y = pmax(x, y))
```

Which gives the same result.

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: so, in this case, do we have to use intermediate variable `X` to reach the goal if we use `dplyr`?

Comment: I don't think there's a direct equivalent of `transform` in dplyr - there is quite some effort put in to making `mutate` behave in this way, and if you want the behaviour of `transform`, then there is no reason to change it. `transform` works well in the pipe and mostly does what `mutate` does, except the (often desirable) ability to sequentially change variables as you have demonstrated.

Comment: ^ Very useful comment, could be in answer to show how to use transform in pipe: `df %>% transform(x = pmin(x, y),y = pmax(x, y))` (or use base R pipe `|>` instead of `%>%`.

Comment: @JonSpring fair enough - the answer is better with the comment inserted. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A quick "hack" could be to not use the data mask and refer explicitly to `df$x`:

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(5), y = rnorm(5), val = sample(letters, 5))

df |> 
  mutate(x = pmin(x, y), y = pmax(df$x, y))
#>            x         y val
#> 1  0.2655087 1.2724293   j
#> 2  0.3721239 0.4146414   v
#> 3 -1.5399500 0.5728534   n
#> 4 -0.9285670 0.9082078   z
#> 5 -0.2947204 0.2016819   g
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The question effectively asks to apply `min` and `max` to rows (rather than to columns). We can use the `rowwise()` operator.

The hitch is that we can't use column names `x` and `y` in the middle of the calculation. So I assign the results to (temporary) columns `min_xy` and `max_xy` instead.

```r
library("tidyverse")

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = runif(5), y = rnorm(5), val = sample(letters, 5))
```

```r
df2 <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    min_xy = min(x, y),
    max_xy = max(x, y)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>       x      y val   min_xy max_xy
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 0.266  1.27  j      0.266  1.27 
#> 2 0.372  0.415 v      0.372  0.415
#> 3 0.573 -1.54  n     -1.54   0.573
#> 4 0.908 -0.929 z     -0.929  0.908
#> 5 0.202 -0.295 g     -0.295  0.202
```

It's easy to rename the columns (though in general I think it's better to keep both the original and the processed columns).

```r
df2 %>%
  select(
    x = min_xy,
    y = max_xy,
    val
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>        x     y val  
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1  0.266 1.27  j    
#> 2  0.372 0.415 v    
#> 3 -1.54  0.573 n    
#> 4 -0.929 0.908 z    
#> 5 -0.295 0.202 g
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>